# informix stores date with a 2 digit year instead of 4, how do I correct this?

Tags: sql, informix

How do I make informix handle 4 digit years?

I have both windows and suse servers using informix

Thank you.

Comment: See my edit for more information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The values of [DBDATE](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/idshelp/v10/topic/com.ibm.sqlr.doc/sqlrmst182.htm) and [DBCENTURY](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/idshelp/v10/topic/com.ibm.sqlr.doc/sqlrmst181.htm) affect the number of digits in the year.

DBDATE defaults to MDY4/ (for the US English locale) which includes a four-digit year.

DBCENTURY controls how to interpret data that includes two-digit years.

See also [GL_DATE](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/idshelp/v10/topic/com.ibm.jdbc_pg.doc/jdbc182.htm) and [DBTIME](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/idshelp/v10/topic/com.ibm.sqlr.doc/sqlrmst195.htm).

**Edit:**

A DATE type stores an integer number of days since December 31, 1899 in four bytes which will handle dates for 2^31 days which is over 5.8 million years into the future.

A DATETIME type can store anything from milliseconds to years in a size that's appropriate to the precision.

See [Chronological Data Types](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/idshelp/v10/topic/com.ibm.ddi.doc/ddi63.htm) which says, in part:

> To customize this DATETIME format,
>   choose your locale appropriately or
>   set the GL_DATETIME or DBTIME
>   environment variable. For more
>   information about these environment
>   variables, see the IBM Informix: GLS
>   User's Guide.

Comment: am i right in understanding this mean that informix *stores* the date properly, but as default only displays the year as two characters?

Comment: I tried setting the global variable GL_DATE = %d/%m/5Y, and it works in command promp, but it shows 2 digits on my web services and server studio :(

Comment: You'll probably need to dig into the SQL code. Here's some more information: https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/library/techarticle/dm-0510roy/

Comment: @MidnighToker: yes - Informix stores the date unambiguously, but you can control the way it displays it.  I always run with DBDATE='Y4MD-' set so my DATE values appear as '2010-04-08' etc by default.  As Dennis said, there are lots of ways of refining this.  Note that the DATETIME variants store the values accurately too - but using a different storage notation.  Both DATE and DATETIME values are restricted to the range 0001-01-01 .. 9999-12-31; I plan to start work on the Y10K problem on 5000-01-02 (assuming I'm still paying attention to anything on that date).